# Membership end date not updated for autorenew monthly

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, recurring-contributions, iats, auto-renew

Ever since upgrading Civi in May to 4.7.19 (currently running 4.7.22), membership end dates are not getting updated for monthly autorenewing memberships.  The completed contribution record is no longer being attached to the membership (thus no update to the end date).  Earlier contribution records which worked have the membership type in the amount_level field in the civicrm_contribution table. New ones are NULL :/

Using iATS and drupal.

Comment: Can you check your iATS version? This is definitely supported functionality for iATS + CiviCRM 4.7 + Drupal.

Comment: 1.6.0 (latest version)

Comment: That sounds like you've got an edge case of some kind with your install. The change that happened with the iATS extension for the 4.7 upgrade is that it started doing things "by the book", using the "repeattransaction" API to handle the connection to the membership when generating a recurring contribution. I'd be happy to dig a little deeper and see what's going on, try contacting me, e.g. via https://blackflysolutions.ca/contact, and/or post some more details on the issue queue here: https://github.com/iATSPayments/com.iatspayments.civicrm/issues

Comment: Can someone comment on if this happens when someone does an ad-hoc "Card on File" charge or does it happen when the scheduled job runs?