# 'Card on File' ad hoc Recurring Payments - Do they link to membership?

Tags: iats

On the latest and greatest.

If we run a card on file payment for a recurring payment profile tied to a membership, we are noticing the payment does not show up as a linked payment when viewing their membership. Is this by design or an error?

edit - [Membership end date not updated for autorenew monthly](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20014/membership-end-date-not-updated-for-autorenew-monthly)

think it's this. any tips?

Comment: civicrm_membership is linked to civicrm_contribution_recur properly and the payments have a link to the recurring profile ID so it "should work"

used this query to find any that were missing: 
SELECT cc.contact_id AS contact_id, cc.id as contribution_id,cm.id as membership_id FROM civicrm_contribution cc, civicrm_membership cm WHERE cc.id NOT IN (SELECT contribution_id FROM civicrm_membership_payment) and cc.contribution_recur_id is NOT NULL and cm.contribution_recur_id = cc.contribution_recur_id

and then we can use an INSERT to remedy - but moving forward?